# Extra "a" element added to page when loaded in browser

Tags: html, css

I am working on the following HTML page which uses links floating over an image to navigate to other pages.

```css
.main{
    width:100vw;
}

.image_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.map_image{
    width:100%;
}

.map_cell {
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
}

.box_link{
    display:block;
}

.test {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.test2 {
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.image_container img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="image_container">
            <img class="map_image" src="" alt="World Map" />
            <a href="westernLandsNorth.html" class="map_cell box_link test" id="west_continent_north" style="top:6%; left:1%; bottom:67%; right:79%"/>
            <a href="westernLandsSouth.html" class="map_cell box_link test2" id="west_continent_south" style="top:33%; left:8%; bottom:34%; right:63%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The source code as viewed both when I write it, and when viewed with Chrome's "show-source" function both look exactly how I wrote it, but the source viewed in chrome's F12 developer tools places an extra `<a>` element after the `</div>` tag closing `<div class="main>`. The extra element is visible as a blue box, it looks identical to the first "west_continent_south" element except with a larger size.

Running the code on StackOverflow has similar results.

Why is that extra element being added? How can I prevent it from being added?

Comment: Anchors aren't self-closing, so the HTML you posted is invalid and the browser is compensating.

Comment: @j08691 Can you leave that as an answer? I assumed closing with "/>" would be sufficient. Closing instead with "</a>" removes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors aren't self-closing, so the HTML you posted is invalid and the browser is compensating.

Answer (score 1):

In XML, any tag can be self-closing. That means, in XML, `<tag></tag>` is the same as `<tag/>` for all values of "tag".

This is **not** the case for HTML. If an HTML tag should be closed, it should be explicitly closed with a standalone closing tag. Strictly speaking, HTML5 has a list of "void tags". Here is the comprehensive list:

> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

For these tags, and these tags only, a closing tag is not required. You can simply type `<tag>` and be done.

Void tags can be *optionally* closed, either via an explicit standalone closing tag (`<tag></tag>`) or via the self-closing syntax that XML uses (`<tag/>`). Doing so has no particular advantage and is neither discouraged nor encouraged.

So, for void tags, and for void tags *only*, any of the following syntaxes are valid:

```
<tag>
<tag/>
<tag></tag>
```

The `a` tag is *not* a void tag. For this tag, *only* the following syntax is valid:

```
<tag></tag>
```

The browser doesn't recognize the self-closing format you used for the `a` tag. Therefore, it makes the only assumption it can: that you meant to create an opening tag. When the browser reaches the end of the document structure, it is still expecting that the `a` tag must be closed -- and since you didn't insert a closing tag, the browser inserts one for you just before closing the document.

To avoid this kind of mistake in the future, you can [automatically verify your document's markup validity against the HTML5 spec](https://validator.w3.org/). In this case, the validation results match what I've described above:

> **Error**: Self-closing syntax (`/>`) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.
>       From line 10, column 13; to line 10, column 150
>
> **Error**: Start tag `a` seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>       From line 11, column 13; to line 11, column 152
>
> **Error**: Self-closing syntax (`/>`) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag. From line 11, column 13; to line 11, column 152
>
> **Error**: End tag `div` seen, but there were open elements. From line 12, column 9; to line 12, column 14
>
> **Error**: Unclosed element `a`. From line 11, column 13; to line 11, column 152
>
> **Error**: End tag `div` seen, but there were open elements. From line 13, column 5; to line 13, column 10
>
> **Error**: End tag for `body` seen, but there were unclosed elements. From line 14, column 1; to line 14, column 7